# Can we assign values to objects passed in arguments without using return in Java?

Tags: java, recovery

This might be the silliest question anybody ever asked, but just for curiosity, Can we assign values to Objects which are passed as arguments. For example

```
public class ForDemo3 {
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList cp = new ArrayList();

    public ForDemo3() {
        int j = 30;
        cp.add(j);
        cp.add(i);
        i = 5;
        j = 12;
        System.out.println("i = " + i + " & j= " + j);
        assignDvalues(i, j);
        System.out
                .println("After Restoring the values i = " + i + " & j= " + j);
    }

    public void assignDvalues(Object... obj) {
        for (int n = 0; n <= obj.length - 1; n++) {
            obj[n] = cp.get(n);
            System.out.println("" + obj[n]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ForDemo3();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to develop checkpoint based recovery in java. And `cp` is a checkpoint object where values can be stored.

Output of Above is

```
  i = 5 & j= 12
  30
  0
  After Restoring the values i = 5 & j= 12
```

Edit
Apologies i am not a great user of stackoverflow. I'm working on a framework for parallel computing. And there will be a function `savecheckpoint(List l)` which will be used to store list or array list to DB as a checkpoint, and another function`public object restoreCheckPoint(int i)` will restore the list. So far i'm able to save the checkpoint and then restore it back. But how can i assign back the values of the Objects or variables without effecting user's code? As given in the above example i want to restore the values using `assignDvalues()`. Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: In effect, Java parameters on a call are copied to local variables inside the called method.  You can modify those values, but any change you make is not reflected back to the caller.

Comment: Is there any way to solve the problem with minimal change in code(in main program) or may be by creating external library. Actually i'm working on a framework for parallel computing and i want that minimal changes occur in user's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a real hack, so use it wisely. Following method uses reflection and has two limitations. Can not handle primitive types (because of autoboxing) and can not handle Strings initialised as constants (i.e. `String s = "some string"` is not supported, but `String s = new String("some string")` works fine). Also you should use `new Integer(X)` instead of `int x` not to mess the primitive types (similar story to Strings)

In belows example I replaced the `int i` with `Integer i` and the same for `j` because as I said primitives are not supported.

The only thing which you would need to require by your users is to use "Integer" instead of "int", "Long" instead of "long" etc. and, what can be painful, avoid Strings defined as constants.

```
public class Demo2 {
  Integer i = 0;
  ArrayList cp = new ArrayList();

  public Demo2() {
    Integer j = 30; 
    String s = "def";
    cp.add(j);
    cp.add(i);
    cp.add(s);
    i = new Integer(5); // you need to use "i = new Integer(5)" instead of "i = 5" because you risk with messing the primitive int 5
    j = new Integer(12); // here also you need to use new Integer(12)
    s = new String("some string"); // NOTE: don't even try this with s ="some string" because this will lead to unexpected behaviour

    //s = "some string"  - if you pass string initialized this way you will mess up the string "some string" in jvm string pool
    System.out.println("i = " + i + " & j= " + j + " & s= " + s);
    assignDvalues(i, j, s);
    System.out.println("After Restoring the values i = " + i + " & j= " + j + " & s= " + s);

  }


  public void assignDvalues(Object... obj) {
    try {
      for (int n = 0; n <= (obj.length - 1); n++) {
        if (obj[n] instanceof Integer) {
          Integer curInt = (Integer) obj[n];
          Field field = curInt.getClass().getDeclaredField("value"); // Integer stores the real value in private field "value"
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.set(curInt, cp.get(n));
          System.out.println("" + obj[n]);
        } else if (obj[n] instanceof String) {
          String curS = (String) obj[n];
          Field field = curS.getClass().getDeclaredField("value"); // String stores the text as char sequence in private field "value"
          field.setAccessible(true);

          Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
          modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
          modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL); // need to reset final flag to override value of String

          field.set(curS, ((String) cp.get(n)).toCharArray());
          System.out.println("" + obj[n]);
        } // else if (obj[n] insteanceOf SomeOtherType) { // you should provide implementation specific for each type/class you want to support with assignDvalues method

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Demo2();
  }

}
```

Comment: Altering immutable objects through reflection is truly the mother of all hack - there is absolutely, positively, no way to use it "wisely". Your code has the potential of breaking things in your system quite unexpectedly: recall that instances of small `Integer` wrappers are shared. Once you change the value inside an `Integer` representing, say, 30, to make it 31, all autoboxed values of 30, in all collections throughout your system will become 31 automatically. Although Java for some unknown reason does not prohibit this, there is absolutely no reason to use this hack in a program.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I known what you mean. Thanks to point this out, but the solution here is still to use `i = new Integer(5)` instead of `i = 5`. Yur comment was however important to make this work correctly. I already edited the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight To comment on your doubt "Although Java for some unknown reason does not prohibit this" I can say that java wants to give you some feeling of freedom (there are no pointers like in C, but there is reflection which can do some tricks, as in this example). Why does java allow this? Well you should know what you are doing. After all you are messing your program/jvm. And to answer on argument that you can mess another program running on the same jvm, the answer is java.lang.SecurityManager#checkMemberAccess which can be used to block this hack.

Comment: Thanks sir for the time it is an acceptable answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, nothing detectable happens: the array of objects is created implicitly by the compiler, so you get no access to it. In addition, primitive `int`s are autoboxed into immutable `Integer`s, so the changes made in the method cannot become visible to the caller through mutability of the objects themselves.

However, if you pass an array explicitly, the assignments are going to stay:

```
Object[] args = new Object[] {i, j};
assignDvalues(args);
System.out.println(args[0]+" "+args[1]);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/yw8yzI)

Comment: Sorry, for that time it seemed like problem can be solved but how can i assign the values back to i and j without changing users code at large scale.

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 That's the thing, you cannot do that: like all primitive data types, `int`s are passed by value (references to reference objects are also passed by value, but that is a different topic altogether). Java does not provide any way to pass parameters by reference, so there is absolutely no way to change `i` or `j` in the calling method by anything that you could possibly do inside the `assignDvalues` method.

Answer (score 1):

Java supports call by value. That means object references are passed as value when a function is called.
However, if you have a vector or ArrayList, then you can pass the vector or ArrayList object reference as an argument of a function, say f(ArrayList a) and within the function, you can insert items to the vector or arraylist just passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an object passed to a method to another object as far as the caller is concerned. Although you can change the *state* of passed objects.

In your example, your attempt at assigning a new value to the parameter array will have no effect on the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case.

Parameters in Java either have a primitive type or are references.  They are passed by value, which means that the method has its own local copy of each parameter of a primitive type, or a local copy of each *reference*.  If your method assigns to the parameter, the method modifies its own local copy, but the assignment doesn't affect anything the caller will see.  However, if the method uses a reference to modify a field in another object, the caller **will** see a change in the referenced object; the method makes local copies of the reference, but not a local copy of the object itself.

An array is an object, so if you have an array parameter, a reference is passed; if the method uses that reference to modify the elements of the array, the caller will be able to see the change to the array element.

A vararg parameter is a special case.  It is passed as an array, which is passed by reference.  So if you write

```
public void assignSomething(Object... obj) {
    obj[0] = "abcde";
}
```

If you call it like this:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[1];
assignSomething(objects);
System.out.println(objects[0]);
```

it will actually print `"abcde"`.  But if you pass individual arguments instead of an array:

```
Object obj1;
Object obj2;
assignSomething(obj1, obj2);
System.out.println(obj1);
```

The program creates a *temporary* array whose values are references to the objects you pass.  The method will then replace the first reference in the temporary array (`obj[0]`) with a new one, but it will not use the previous value of the array element, which is the reference to `obj1`.  So even though assigning an array element is normally a change that can be seen by the caller, in this case the element that gets assigned is part of a "hidden" array that nobody can see.

So, no, `obj1` won't be affected--and in your example, `i` and `j` similarly won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by packing your object into another object. Assume you create generic wrapper class:

```
class ObjectHolder<T> {
  private T obj;

  private ObjectHolder(T obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  public static ObjectHolder of(Object o) {
    return new ObjectHolder(o);
  }

  public T getValue() {
    return obj;
  }

  public void setValue(T value) {
    obj = value;

  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return obj.toString();
  }
}
```

Now you can rewrite your program using that wrapper:

```
public class ForDemo3 {
  ObjectHolder<Integer> i = ObjectHolder.of(0);
  ArrayList cp = new ArrayList();

  public ForDemo3() {
    ObjectHolder<Integer> j = ObjectHolder.of(30);
    cp.add(j.getValue());
    cp.add(i.getValue());
    i.setValue(5);
    j.setValue(12);
    System.out.println("i = " + i + " & j= " + j);
    assignDvalues(i, j);
    System.out.println("After Restoring the values i = " + i + " & j= " + j);
  }

  public void assignDvalues(ObjectHolder... obj) {
    for (int n = 0; n <= (obj.length - 1); n++) {
      obj[n].setValue(cp.get(n));
      System.out.println("" + obj[n].getValue());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ForDemo3();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, i'm working on a framework for parallel computing. One of the objective of my project is that user has to do minimal change in his/her code. If you have another suggestion i will be glad to know. :)

Comment: Could you give more details (you can edit your post)? What do you mean by "user code"? Do you mean that your method `void assignDvalues(Object... obj)`  must take `Object...` as a parameter, so that it can be called with any types  by users??

Comment: Yes sir, that is what i'm trying to achieve. :)

Comment: See my another answer (posted a moment ago) for a possible "hack" how you can achieve this :)